# If black holes contain dark energy would the expansion of the universe be uniform?

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, dark-energy

Because black holes are different sizes presumably they would contain different quantities of dark energy and so some galaxies would accelerate faster in some directions than others.

[Dark energy from supermassive black holes? Physicists spar over radical idea](https://www.science.org/content/article/dark-energy-supermassive-black-holes-physicists-spar-over-radical-idea)

Answer (score 1):

**In that model, black holes are assumed to spread out uniformly throughout the universe after their formation.** This is typical behavior for dynamical dark energy models, but it's particularly necessary here to evade established observational constraints on the abundance of massive black holes within galaxies. In Appendix B of [their ApJ Letter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.07878), where the authors demonstrate their model's compatibility with these limits, they say that they "have assumed a uniformly dispersed population in the computation of Figure 3". It is also clear from the referenced figure that this assumption has indeed been made.

(Whether the implied departure of stellar remnants from galaxies is itself consistent with observations is a separate matter that, to my knowledge, has not been addressed.)

Comment: Stellar-remnant black holes *do* remain in galaxies -- that's where we've seen them! (Both via accretion disks from companion stars and from [microlensing](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac739e).)

Comment: And, no, the model doesn't assume that black holes "spread out uniformly throughout the universe".

Comment: @PeterErwin I agree that stellar remnant black holes stay in galaxies (and that's one reason why the black holes as dark energy idea makes no sense)

Comment: @PeterErwin But the people proposing the idea do assume that black holes spread out uniformly. See section 4.1 and appendix B of https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.07878

Comment: @Sten How would black holes spread out  uniformly  if they expand space at different rates? This is like  energy being asymmetrical ly distributed as shown by the CMB fluctuations

Comment: @DaveTheWave The suggested mechanism is that there is a pressure-like effect ("anisotropic stress" in the linked article) that drives the black hole distribution toward uniformity. This doesn't have to be the case, but if it is not, then the model is already ruled out at the 4-5 order of magnitude level by (at least) microlensing.

Comment: If dark energy is vacuum fluctuations then as a black hole increases its mass it increases its entropy and gains information  Isn't this problematic and similar to the information loss paradox.  Something must be losing entropy / information to balance the situation and if that something is the space around the black hole then that space will lose vacuum energy to the black hole and will shrink not expand !

Comment: @Sten There’s nothing in the article (either the _Science_ news piece or the _ApJ Letter_) about BHs being “driven toward uniformity”.

Comment: @Sten Looking at some of the earlier articles, the idea seems to be that _if_ you have a population of dark-energy-filled black holes formed at $z \sim 10-20$ from Pop III stars, and _if_ these objects have extremely high spins, then you can supposedly get a large scale repulsive effect that might produce “uniformity”, before most galaxy formation. They note that the observed spins of present-day stellar-mass black holes are much too low to qualify.

Comment: E.g., [Croker et al. 2020](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/abad2f)

Comment: @PeterErwin Regardless of earlier work, when assessing compatibility with microlensing/wide binary/ultrafaint dwarf constraints in the recent Letter (that I linked), they assume the black holes are uniformly distributed. Notice how in figure 3, the black holes are taken to contribute $\sim 10^{-5}$ the local density of the Milky Way halo. If the black holes remained clustered, they would contribute the majority of the halo's density, violating the observational limits horrendously.

Comment: @PeterErwin The relevant text in Appendix B is, "Consistent with the discussion in §4.1, we have assumed a uniformly dispersed population in the computation of Figure 3"

Comment: I think the paper is just wrong. I wrote [this answer](//physics.stackexchange.com/a/751748) about it. Their assumption that the mass of the quasi-black-hole objects depends on the scale factor is inconsistent with general relativity.

Comment: @benrg Totally agree that the theoretical basis for the model is in error.

Comment: @Sten Hmm.... I think I agree with you now: they do assume a uniform density of BHs, even though that requires implausibly high spins and contradicts the observed distribution of the supermassive BHs they're basing the paper's argument on...

Comment: @benrg I think your argument in that physics.stackexchange answer is wrong; I just added a comment there about that. (I do agree that the paper is wrong, but for more observational reasons.)